# im having a problem in javascript output it is not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to solve this question with CSS, form, javascript and I tried to do javascript and included 3 if statements but it not really showing me the output
is it because the if statements should each be closed with brackets? or maybe there is a mistake in the way I write the variables I tried many things, and it's not working please help I'm still a beginner programmer and I can't figure it out

```js
  

 function myFunction(){
          
var Fname= document.getElementById("fname").value;
var Lname= document.getElementById("lname").value;
var Name = Fname + "   " + Lname;

var date= document.getElementById("date").value;



var tr= document.getElementById("t").value;

var tour= document.getElementById("tour").value;

var request= document.getElementById("request").value;

var v = Number(document.getElementById("visitor").value);
var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
var x="";
var y="";
var z="";
    var total=x+y+z;



{
        if (v<=0){

                v=prompt(" minimum visitors are 1 try again");
                }
             
            
         else if (city == "Amman $50") {
         x = v * 50; 
         } 

         else if (city == "Salt $20")  {

         x = v * 20;
         }  

         else   {

         x = v * 10;
         }

  }
  
  {
  
           if ( tour==Yes )
                 {
             y= 50;
                  }
            else {
             y=x;
                 }
               }

{              

            if (trans==Car)
                {
                z= 30;
                        }

                 else{
                 z=20;
                      }
    
    }

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Arrival date" + date + "<br>"
+ Name.toUpperCase() + 
"<br>"+" City " + city + v + "visitors"
+"<br>" + " transportation " + tr + 
"<br>" + "tour leader :" + tour 
"<br>"+ "any medical:" + request +
"<br>" +"Amount=$ " + total ;

return false;
};
```

```css
  

 body{
margin:20px;
text-align:center;
}

form{
background-color:orange;
}

div.sec {
margin-left:300px;
}




div.transpo {
margin-right:450px;
}
```

```html
<h3 style="text-align:center"> <span style="color:red;font-size:40px;">V</span>isit <span style="color:red;font-size:40px;">J</span> ordan </h3>

<form>
  <div class="transpo">
    <input type="text" id="fname" size="30" placeholder="First Name">
    <br><br>
    <select id="city">
      <option value="select your city "> Select your city </option>
      <option value="50 ">Amman $50</option>
      <option value="20 ">Salt $20</option>
      <option value="10 ">Jarash $10</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <label><b>Number of visitors</b></label>
    <br>
    <input type="number" id="visitor">

    <br><br>

    <label style="margin-right:10px;"><b> Transportation</b></label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="car" name="transportation" value="car" id="t">
    <label id="car" for="car">car $30</label>
    <input type="radio" id="bus" name="transportation" value="bus" id="t">
    <label for="bus">bus 20$</label><br>
  </div>

  <div class="sec">
    <input type="text" id="lname" size="30" placeholder="Last Name">

    <br><br>
    <label><b>Arrival Date:</b></label><br>
    <input type="date" id="date">

    <br><br>

    <label><b> Any medical Request:</b></label>
    <br>
    <textarea rows="1" cols="20" id="request"></textarea>

    <br><br>
    <label><b> Tour Leader $50</b></label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="yes" name="tour" value="yes" id="tour">
    <label for="yes">yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="no" name="tour" value="no" id="tour">
    <label for="no">no</label><br>
  </div>





  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> PREVIEW </button>
  <button type="submit" onClick=""> Submit </button>
</form>

<p style="background-color:#99ccff;width:420px;font-weight: bold;" id="result"> </p>

<p style="background-color:#99ccff;width:420px;font-weight: bold;" id="result2"> </p>
```

Comment: Check your browser console and see if you have errors

Comment: The console says `Invalid or unexpected token line 122`. You are missing a few characters at `+ "visitors
  "<br>" +`. Your script crashes at start, it's not even running at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your console in your browser (pressing F12 as default) you can see that the Javascript is returning an error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: "" string literal contains an unescaped line break
```

This refers two missing quote marks on row 174 and row 176, both are missing on the end of the file.

However your code still don't work, if you press preview you get another error

```
<input type="radio" id="car" name="transportation" value="car" id="t">
<input type="radio" id="bus" name="transportation" value="bus" id="t">
```

on these two lines you specify id twice which is not allowed.

Tips so you can more easily solve these issues on your own:

- You should start to use the console to find errors in your code.
- Try to reread your code and look for small errors like a missing "
- If you are unsure how something works like a html or javascript feature use websites like w3school to look up well expained documentation.

Good luck in your future coding adventures.